# High low game logic for win

Tags: java

Lost Newbie!
please improve the code it never shows the conditions. As well as i need to put four wins in a row for the user to win. please help!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;


public class HiLoGame {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

    String guess=null;
    String high= "high";
    String low="low";
    String equal = "equal";
    int nextCard;
    int card=3;
    System.out.println("Current card is: "+ card);
    if(card==11){
        System.out.println ("Which means it is card jack!");
    }else if(card==12){
        System.out.print("which means it is card queen!");
    }else if(card==13){
        System.out.println("Which means it is card king!");
    }else if (card==14){
        System.out.println("Which means it is card Ace!");
    }   
    System.out.println("WELCOME! to High-Low game.");
    System.out.println("Guess four times in a row to win.");

    while(true){
    Random generator = new Random();
    nextCard = generator.nextInt(14)+1;
    System.out.println("Next card will be high, low or equal?");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    guess = input.next();
    System.out.println("It is --> "+ nextCard);
        card = generator.nextInt(14)+2;
        nextCard = generator.nextInt(14)+2;
        System.out.println("Next card will be high, low or equal?");
        Scanner input1  = new Scanner(System.in);
        guess = input1.next();
        System.out.println("It is --> "+ nextCard);
        while(true){
        if (guess.equals(high))
        {        
            if (card < nextCard) 
            {
                System.out.println("NICE GUESS ");
                System.out.println("KEEP PLAYING");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry WRONG GUESS!");
                System.out.println("Better luck next time");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        else if  (guess.equals(low))
        {
            if (card > nextCard)
            {
                System.out.println("NICE GUESS");
                System.out.println("KEEP PLAYING");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry WRONG GUESS!");
                System.out.println("Better luck next time");
            }
        }
        else if(guess.equals(equal)) 
        {

            if (card==nextCard)
            {
                System.out.println("NICE GUESS");
                System.out.println("KEEP PLAYING");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry WRONG GUESS");
                System.out.println("Better luck next time!");
                System.exit(0);
            }


        }
    }}}}
```

Comment: I've deleted your [tag:javascript] tag as your question has nothing to do with use of this language. Please understand that these are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help.

Comment: Also your question has nothing to do with Swing or cardslib, and these tags have been deleted. What gives? You are new, but please strive to be accurate with your questions and tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is a bit strange and confusing but I have taken the time to go through it, any questions feel free to ask:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class HiLoGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random generator = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String guess = null, result = null;
        Boolean won = false;
        int nextCard, card = 3, count = 0;
        System.out.println("Current card is: " + card);
        switch (card) {
            case 11:
                System.out.println("Which means it is card jack!");
                break;
            case 12:
                System.out.print("which means it is card queen!");
                break;
            case 13:
                System.out.print("which means it is card king!");
                break:
            case 14:
                System.out.println("Which means it is card Ace!");
                break;
        }

        System.out.println("WELCOME! to High-Low game.\nGuess four times in a row to win.");

        while (!won) {

            nextCard = generator.nextInt(14) + 1;

            System.out.println("You current card is: " + card + "\nWill the next card be high, low or equal?");

            guess = input.next().toLowerCase();
            System.out.println("The next card is:" + nextCard);

            if(card<nextCard){
                result = "high";
            }
            else if(card>nextCard){
                result = "low";
            }
            else if(card==nextCard){
                result = "equal";
            }

            if(guess.equals(result)){
                System.out.println("NICE GUESS\nKEEP PLAYING");
                card = nextCard;
                count++;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Sorry WRONG GUESS!\nBetter luck next time");
                count=0;
            }

            if(count==4){
                System.out.println("Congratulations, you have beaten the game!!!\nWould you like to play again? Yes/No");
                guess = input.next().toLowerCase();
                if(guess.equals("yes"))
                {
                    count = 0;
                    card = generator.nextInt(14) + 1;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Thank you for playing, goodbye");
                    System.exit(0);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck with your learning!

A few of the things used in this code compared to the code in question are:

I have used a switch block, this is used instead of multiple if statements, you can pass in the variable and then in the line: case you put in what you want to match it against, this looks a lot nicer and is much more efficient than using multiple if statements.

I have also used a \n in the printline this is the escape xhar for a newline. You can use this instead of multiple print line statements.

You should try in your code to minimise the amount of repeated text, my code is far from perfect but if it was then you wouldn't have anything to look into.

Instead of calling multiple if statements also try doing one set of if statements to check a condition and then save the result in advance, this changes the amount of comparisons...

Hopefully that makes sense to you.

Comment: Not much of a Java programmer personally, haven't touched it for a while, can't remember what I used to use for string comparison, I have used string == string before but it's not a perfect way of comparing, probably better for demonstration tho. Not sure what you are referring to in terms of the switch block other than it is missing the default case which I have  forgot to put in.

Comment: zenon bruratta thank you for the time! however my code seems confusing because lack of actual question mentioned